# Can't view thumbnail created in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create my own thumbnails within the Django admin and I believe they are being properly pointed to. However I cannot view the thumbnail. This is what I see:

[image]

When I click on the thumbnail, I get redirected to this URL and all I see is an empty white page.

`http://localhost:8000/media/media/Screen_Shot_2016-04-08_at_12.55.25_PM.png`

It is the correct URL but I do not see anything within the page.

Here is what code I have:

Within my settings.py

All files will go to `cherngloong/uploads` and `/media/` will be the public front facing representation of the `MEDIA_ROOT`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Within cherngloong/cherngloong/urls.py I appended to the list to serve static files:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="index"),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My cherngloong/api/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'ig$', most_recent)
]
```

cherngloon/api/models.py:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="media/", default=None)
```

cherngloong/api/admin.py:

```
class MediaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["name", "file"]
    list_display = ("name", "media_type", "url", "album", "display", "thumbnail")
    def display(self, media_obj):
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (media_obj.file.url, media_obj.file.name)

    def thumbnail(self, media_obj):
        location = media_obj.file.url
        thumbnail_html = "<a href=\"{0}\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"{1}\" height=\"80\" /></a>".format(location, location)
        return thumbnail_html

    thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    display.allow_tags = True
```

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Try copying your code into the django shell and seeing if the value of thumbnail_html is actually what you expect?

Comment: @TimS. Yup tried it but still no picture =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any inconsistency on the code you have. I just created a project on GitHub with the same structure, and code you posted here, and everything worked like a charm, you can test it yourself, see the code here: https://github.com/vladir/cherngloong. I used the last version of `Django`, I know you are using a version below `Django 1.9` because you are still using `allow_tags`, but even so your code seems good for me. Perhaps my code can help you to find what is happening.

I found why it is happening. Remove this line:

`url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="index"),`

from your `cherngloong/cherngloong/urls.py`, and it will render ok.

It seems as this URL is too open, and it interferes with the thumbnails URL.
It could work for you instead:
`url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="index"),`

I updated my code on the repo, so that you can test that it is working.

Comment: I'm actually using version 1.9. I used `allow_tags` because I was getting influence from a previous unfinished project of mine. Would that make a difference?

Comment: It does not make a difference, at least you would get the html as a text there, but it was deprecated, please check here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#s-id1. The URL pattern I posted does the fix for your problem, though. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Here is a link to my project: https://github.com/liondancer/cherngloong  In the mean time, I'll take a look at the example project. Thanks!

Comment: This definitely helped. I am running `react-router` and `reactjs` with my django project so I needed the URL you suggested to be open. What fixed it was appending an open URL to the end after it's been initialized. Not sure why only then it worked... Here's what I mean: http://dpaste.com/1ZFFNBD

Comment: I see, good catch! I'm happy that you could solve that. Thanks for the details